# Не работает Yandex Mobile Ads Unity,

Tags: unity3d

Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с подобной ситуацией в Yandex Mobile Ads Unity, где реклама нормально загружается, но при вызове метода Show приложение зависает. Даже пример по-прежнему вызывает эту проблему, и я не могу найти причину.

Answer (score 0):

В <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> укажите <kbd>Minimum API Level</kbd> не ниже API level 31.

Answer (score 0):

Решил аналогичную проблему, поставив галочки:

(Build Settings → Player Settings → Publishing Settings → Build)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Документация (Ошибки при интеграции плагина): [Yandex](https://yandex.ru/support2/mobile-ads/ru/dev/unity/unity-errors#sobytie-dismissed-srabatyvaet-odnovremenno-s-shown-i-polnoekrannaya-reklama-ne-pokazyvaetsya)